# Rails3 User Changed Password, how do I change the current session password?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I have the need to let the user change their password.  I'd like to switch the password in the session to reflect this new password, without logging them out.

```
def set_auth username, password
    # test username and password here?
    auth_object = AuthCookie.new
    auth_object.set_username username
    auth_object.set_password password
    session[:user_login] = auth_object
end
```

I use something like the above, but it doesn't seem to work in changing the current session's password to the new one the use just entered.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you store their password in the session anyway? Isn't it enough to know that the user has successfully authenticated?

Comment: You have skipped some details here. What is not working for you? Share the details of the code which indicates failure. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Don't save your whole auth object in the session, the most important thing is you should not save password info in the session. Rails default session storage is cookie based, just base64 encode string. So if you save user password info in the session, there is security problem.

Just put the user identify in the session, for example, the user_id. `session[:user_id] = user_id`